# Javascript OnDemandGrid and TabContainer

Tags: javascript, dgrid

I have an application where the user enters a value and the application does a query and gets some records returned.

The results are put into two grids: some of the results will go into one grid in one tab, other results will go into another grid in a second tab.

Everything is working fine, except the grid looks bad and I can't seem to figure out how to make it look better.

Problem 1:
Tab1 (tabPOU): Is the selected/active tab. Grid looks ok, but is a little too wide, so the vertical scroll bar is hard to use.
Tab2 (tabPOD): Same problem as in Tab1, but have a real problem here.  The first row of record writes on top of the header.  If I make this the selected tab, the grid looks fine, but then Tab1 has the problem with the first row writing on top of the header.

Problem 2:
This I really don't understand. When I create the grid in my script, I have to put it in the Tab1. It won't work using a div id="grid" within the tab.

I have tried to comment out all the ccs files that could have an effect. Doesn't matter. I've messed with creating new styles with margins and padding. I've tried making things global using window.grid

I can live with the solution for Problem 2, if I have to. But I really need to figure out why my results are mushing together.

The HTML portion:

```
<div id="wrResults" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region: 'bottom'" style="height: 25%">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 90%; ">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="tabPOU" title="POU" data-dojo-props="selected:true" style=" height: 100%; width: 90%; "></div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="tabPOD" title="POD"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript portion:

```
function myWaterRightQuery(qrytype, qry_string ){
require([....
"dgrid/OnDemandGrid", 
"dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
...   ], function(
...
Grid, 
DijitRegistry,
...
) {
parser.parse();
```

go do the query...
put the results in two grids (here is code for one grid)...

```
var pod_store =  new Memory({data: pod_data_list});

pod_grid = new Grid({
    store: pod_store,
    columns:{        
        pod_display: "Water Right",
        wr_type: "Water Type",
        name_first:  "First Name",
        name_last:  "Last Name" ,
        name_company: "Company"
    },
    loadingMessage: "Loading data ...",
    noDataMessage: "No results found.",
}, "tabPOD"); 
pod_grid.startup();
pod_grid.renderArray(pod_data_list);
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You seem to be loading `dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry` but based on the snippets you've included it's not clear whether you're actually mixing it in to your grid constructor (since it looked like `Grid` was simply the name of your local variable for `OnDemandGrid`).

Comment: I guess I'm not actually using it anywhere.

Comment: I believe I have solved this to some extent.  I used both the startup and the renderArray.  If I take out the startup, it works better. There is still a slight shift in the row, but it looks a lot better.